# Apache virtual host on a specific directory

Tags: zend-framework, apache-config

I need my site to have a virtual host on a specific directory for my zend application. When user enters `www.example.com` it should go to normal document root but when user navigates to `www.example.com/cms` it should go to `/var/www/cms/public` which its `.htaccess` file is like this:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

On localhost I added this lines to `/etc/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost  *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/cms/public"
   ServerName persian_literature
   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
   <Directory "/var/www/cms/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now `http://localhost/` goes to `/var/www/cms/public` and every thing works. My question is how should I change change above code, to force `http://localhost/` to be the normal directory root (so I could use other applications) and `http://localhost/cms` to be the virtual host?

Answer (score 3):

A virtual host is done at the hostname/domainname level, not at a directory level. You can use an alias to point the URI /cms to some other directory on your server by putting

```
Alias /cms /var/www/cms/public
```

in a .conf file (this will not work in .htaccess)

Comment: I add that code to `apache.conf`. now `http://localhost/cms/` points to correct location, but other pars of application, such as `http://localhost/cms/member/login` don't work.

Comment: You'd have to tell the cms that it's now living in `/cms`, not `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a symlink (symbolic link)? You still should have the  entry of course. And you'll have to put in the config (vhost config I think, maybe .htaccess) that apache should follow the symlink.